# KerasClassifier and GridSearchCV not finding best parameters?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, gridsearchcv

I am building a neural network model using Keras Functional API, and I am using GridSearchCV with KerasClassifier to find the best parameters for the model. I am using a 6 folds cross-validation, and I am getting an overall 0.9 accuracy with the best params during the search. After running the grid search two times, the output of the function was the same parameters.

The code used to do the searching process is:

```
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=get_model_clas, verbose=0)
grid = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid, verbose=2, n_jobs=-1, cv=6, refit=False)
grid.fit(x, y, validation_split=0.1)
```

However, after finding the best params and training the model using the full dataset, the score obtained after evaluating the model on the test set was very low compared to the one obtained when searching (~0.6).

Code used to train the final model:

```
model = get_model_clas(best_params)
model.fit(x, y, validation_split=0.1)
```

Actually, choosing random parameters, the score obtained is better than the one given by the "best parameters" found by GridSearchCV. So, in the end, all the search process is worthless, because the difference in training over 6 folds and training over the full dataset is really high. How can there be such a big difference if the search is outputting the same params every time it is executed? How can this be improved?

PS: I am using EarlyStopping to prevent overfitting.

Comment: Did you try with `RandomizedSearchCV`

Comment: No, I have a grid with lists of parameters. From what I've seen, `RandomizedSearchCV` is useful for parameter distributions, to pick random values for the parameters. Still, I don't see the difference in using this or `GridSearchCV` if all parameters are picked from a list. In the end, the algorithm is going to use the same parameters

Comment: You can try giving different range in `RandomizedSearchCV` for getting best parameters, Still if you get same parameters then need to look into code in detail.